# Tracking email client opens

Tags: analytics, tracking, html-email

I am slowly making some progress on figuring out how Litmus (litmus.com/analytics) and some other companies actually track email opens by which Email Client the user is using.

I found this really cool article written a long time ago that basically helped me get a start to actually understanding what goes into just simply tracking opens.

http://webanalyticsinsight.wordpress.com/2010/03/04/how-to-track-email-open-rates/

I'm no developer but I'm assuming there must be some sort of get_browser()  that would allow me to do this.

any push in the right direction would help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's done by inserting a small hosted image into each message that is sent.  The URL to the location where the image is hosted is unique for each message, so this way the system can determine which messages have been opened (provided that the recipient's mail client is set to open hosted images).
See: http://ultrasmtp.com/resources/openedmessagealerts.php for more info.

Comment: I completely understand how tracking is done... I'm looking for how to figure out what email client they are using.

Comment: The link to the hosted image points to a script on the server side, which serves up the image.  That script uses the 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' environment variable to determine what type of client the recipient used to open the message.